# CodeIgniter multiple update in the same query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem when I want to update multiple records with the same query in CodeIgniter.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
$query = "UPDATE user_data SET name = 'Name1 Surname1' WHERE uid = 'n1s1'; UPDATE user_data SET name = 'Name2 Surname2' WHERE uid = 'n2s2'";
$this->db->query($query);
```

This returns `false` so the query does not executes with success.

What can I do to run this query in CodeIgniter?

Comment: You are not updating multiple records, you are trying to execute more than 1 query by terminating them with `;`. Short answer is - you can't do that. Split that into 2 queries, wrap them with transaction block and that's it.

Comment: Why not wrapping it in a transaction and make 2 queries (docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html )

Comment: @ka_lin I am concerned about the execution time of those queries. There are about 1000 queries. Is it more performant than trying to do it with simple php (outside CodeIgniter)?

Comment: Two people told you about transaction. You didn't even ask what it means.  No, it's not more performant to do what you want. What's more performant is to use prepared statements and transactions. You're not doing it nor asking what it even is. Yes, it's MUCH faster than to create a huge string and send it to MySQL. Yes, it's fast even if you have tens of thousands of insert / update queries. Don't believe me? Measure it. You'll be surprised. There's a reason why, but it takes too much to explain.

Comment: @N.B. Because I asked this question, this doesn't mean that I am a beginner at databases or queries. I know what transactions are. CodeIgniter is new for me. This is why I don't know what can be done here and what cannot.
Thank your for your comment. I got it that I couldn't execute more than one query.

Comment: If you're not a beginner, you'd know what autocommit is, that what you wanted to do would quickly overflow `max_allowed_packed` setting in MySQL, that prepared statements lex the query once, send the **data** through, avoid the parsing of SQL, avoid the possible `max_allowed_packet` and wrapping it in transaction would use 1 I/O to flush it to HDD, making an effective use of hard drive's bandwith. But, hey, we got caught up in this debate if you're a beginner or not. Knowing how to write a query doesn't make anyone an expert. I never called you a beginner btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transactions.

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query("UPDATE user_data SET name = 'Name1 Surname1' WHERE uid = 'n1s1'");
$this->db->query("UPDATE user_data SET name = 'Name2 Surname2' WHERE uid = 'n2s2'");
$this->db->trans_complete();
```